# How can I add an internet radio station to Banshee?

Tags: banshee

How can I add an internet radio station to Banshee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right-click the **Radio** entry in
  the sidebar.

[image]

- Select **Add Station**.

[image]

- A new window will open, where you
  input the information of the station
  you wish to add.

[image]

Comment: yes i found but i am stuck with stream url. I need to  add this radio http://www.radiojoyalukkas.com/. But don't know how to find the stream url

Comment: There are some radios thaat simply haven't any stream URL. They use other ways to stream music, as flash player.

Comment: aneeshep, I looked through the website, and in the website's CSS code, but could not find a stream URL. Perhaps you could ask in their chatroom when someone is around?

Comment: I think the stream URL is: http://91.121.122.94:8032