# Can I play internet radio that uses the .aspx format in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

I had read how to add internet radio in Banshee : [How can I add an internet radio station to Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39231/how-can-i-add-an-internet-radio-station-to-banshee) But I think it only can play the .pls not aspx. 
Also how that possible to look the stream url of the radio like this: http://91.121.122.94:8032

The radio that I try to add to the banshee: http://radio.mediacorp.sg/RadioLive/xfm963.aspx

Other than using ctrl-i in firefox, how to know the streaming url for the .aspx website?

Comment: There is no need to mark it as [SOLVED] in the title - accepting an answer marks it as solved automatically. :)

Comment: @jrg I'm sorry maybe i should read the faq again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.aspx is the tipical extension for a web page created with the ASP .Net framework, so it's simply not a media file but a container for a web page.

You can investigate all the components presents in that page with some key command, i.e. in Firefox do a CTRL+I and select the media tab, you can browse all the media in that page and reach all the linked contents.

this is probably what you are looking for:

http://www.mediacorpradio.sg/radioliveplayer/asx/xfm963/fm963.asx

and in this case VLC is better than Banshee.